# How to create a multithreaded application that has to call a DLL that blocks everytime is called

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I noticed that my multithreaded application was hardly getting 60% of processing usage even when I put more threads to work. I inspect the code and finally found that probably the calls to a DLL  (Html Agility Pack) are not beign performed asynchroniously. Is there a way to make the calls in parallel?

Comment: Like spawn a new thread and call the blocking methods?

Comment: Show please how do you call dll

Comment: @Likurg I basically create a different document on each thread, and then load a html document, then I do a few xpath queries.

Comment: @Devela, I guess your problem is somewhere in `I basically create a different document on each thread, and then load a html document, then I do a few xpath queries` and we don't know the details.

Comment: @L.B I just create a thread, and instance a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument on each thread call, then I load the document doc.load(string) and then a few xpath queries to it.

Comment: @Devela See the answers.

Answer (score 0):

First Question would be, how do you manage the Threads? I made good experiences by using managed ThreadPools. The System manages it's resources itself.

Sewcond i would recommend you to use Delegates for Calling Methods or DLLs Threadsave and async. About threadpooling there is a good MSDN Article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Here you can find some good Ressource Articles about it:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582/en-us

Please Feedback some Code Examples if this doesn't solve your Problem.

Comment: The problem is not the threads. The problem is calling the functions of the referenced dll. They are called from different threads, but at the end they are somehow being marshaled and called synchronicously.

Answer (score 0):

*@Devela This is not an answer. I write it here since it is a little bit long for a comment.*

I don't think that your problem is related with STA. Just try below code.

```
Action action = () =>
{
    string html = "<html><body><div>1111</div><div>222</div></body></html>";
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var x = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").ToArray();
    var y = x[0].InnerText;
};

while(true)
{
    Parallel.For(0,32,i=>action());
}
```

This code keeps my CPU busy at ~96%. My guess is your threads are getting blocked by some Disk IO, Network Operations etc. therefore you don't see much CPU usage eventhough you add more threads.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right! On each thread I am loading a file that then is loaded in the HtmlAgilityPack. Then all threads write to a single file, where I store the parsed results of all threads. Is that a reason for my processor not using the 40% of the maximum processing power? I have an i7. By the way, I tried eliminating the write operations (to a single file), and it is doesnt seem to be better. So the problem should be when loading the document from the disc? this is something I do one after the other, everytime I load one I create a new thread and send the file as a parameter.